# How can i solve python csv encoding error?

Tags: python

df = pd.read_csv("D:\jihyun0115\desktop\dataframe01.csv")

After this, error code is keep occur.
I already did encoding = 'UTF-8', 'euk-kr', 'cp949' , sep = ',' "r", etc..
do you know what kind of action can solve this ? please help ~~

error code : 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: What are the first few bytes of the file if you `open` and `read` it *as binary*? Well, we already know the first byte is 0xff. My best guess from that is UTF-16 big-endian, which would encode a byte-order mark as 0xff 0xfe.

Comment: @S4RUUL that will definitely not help; Pandas handles that sort of thing for you, and anyway your example is still assuming an encoding that was already tried. The problem is to know which encoding to use.

Comment: There are many encodings that can accept any input data and convert to string, such as `iso-8859-1` - but they may not interpret the data *correctly*, and so they could cause problems for reading the CSV structure. It's at least worth a shot; looking at the results sometimes offers another clue.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thank you so much! i tried UTF-16 with sep='\t' and it's working :)